# Lags on file access, is my HDD going to break?

Tags: hard-disk

Yesterday, I noticed that there is a 5 second delay around those things which used to be instantly. However, it just occurs sometimes, usually only on the first time (maybe kernel cache).

- Opening a new terminal and starting the shell. It takes a while for the prompt to load. This happens in both Fish and Bash
- Opening a file in Vim.
- Launching a command from Awesome WM and using the tab-completion. It takes a while until the completion show up.
- Creating a new commit in git, when I already ran `git status` which usually caches the whole repo.

Each time, I see the HDD LED flicker pretty dimly. I think that means that it is busy, but the read rate is very low. That probably means that the HDD is moving around a lot without a lot of reads.

I have the impression that the harddrive has a physical problem and has to re-read the sectors again and again to come up with the data. The actions used to be faster, though.

Background:

- The drive serves as `/home` and is formatted with EXT4.
- My data is stored in a eCryptfs container.
- The system is a ThinkPad X220 with Kubuntu 14.04.

How can I find out which files got corrupted, if any?

Comment: This question needs to be fixed. You should be asking either 1) How to detect drive failure, or 2) Why these actions are slow. Assuming that they're slow because of drive failure is potentially false assumption, and thus the question would be unanswerable. There are numerous things that can explain this behavior, hdd failure would be probably the last thing on the list. Foremost I would expect problems with name service lookups (dns, usernames, etc).

Comment: Okay, I'll try to improve the question. The thing is that those actions used to be really fast before. My shell behaved strangely starting with the slowness, and I am not sure whether its configuration files got corrupted or it was an update with a new bug in it.

Comment: If the question is "why are these actions slow", are you using anything like `nscd`, `nslcd` or `sssd`? Are you using centralized authentication (ldap, nis, etc)? Do you have any network mounted filesystems?

Comment: No, not at all. I just do a `git commit -a` on my local hard drive. It used to be done immediately, now it sometimes takes either no time or 5 seconds.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're experiencing, my questions still stand. The system can perform all sorts of actions which you might not expect.

Comment: I meant that I was using nothing of the services on my machine. So it might be just software, okay. In case it would be hardware, what could I do now (except backups) that would help me prevent data corruption in the next time?

Comment: If you think it is the hard disk failing, then use `S.M.A.R.T` tools to find out the health of your drive. `fsck` probably won't help. Most modern drives hide failures, by using redundancy, except via `S.M.A.R.T`. But also note it may not be a disk failing, my disk slowed down a while back similar symptoms (only 1second though). It turned out that it was my fault, I had changed something, in the mount options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[smartmon-tools](http://www.smartmontools.org/) may be useful in detection hard failures by the drive. However, the output is difficult to interpret.

On the whole, I tend to agree with @Patrick that it there are more likely causes. But hard-drives do fail. If they are slowly degrading (instead of catastrophic failure like head crashes) the drive controller may use [bad sector replacement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_sector) and sector re-reads to help correct it. This gives inconsistent behavior but smartmon-tools should show record of that.

Comment: I ran `e2fsck -cc` yesterday, and it did not show any errors, as far as I can tell. With SMART, I did not see anything strange. The lags are gone now, though. Maybe it was just temporary or scanning for bad blocks fixed it.